# What's the best way to avoid many if statements in Angular component to call specific function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm creating a temperature conversion app in Angular 7, in my formGroup I have an input/output value, and 2 multi selects where the user can select a unit of temperature 'From' and 'To' to convert(celsius, Fahrenheit or Kelvin).

When the user submit the form in my component I get the input data

```
submitForm(data) {
    this.input = data.input;
    this.unitInput= data.unitInput;
    this.unitTarget= data.unitTarget;
    this.output= data.output;
  }
```

I thought in just adding if statements to call the function that will make the conversion, but now looking at all if statements that i have seems a lot and not a good design.

```
if (this.inputUnit === 'Celsius' && this.targetUnit === 'Fahrenheit') {
        this.celsiusToFahrenheitConversion ();
}
if (this.inputUnit === 'Celsius' && this.targetUnit === 'Kelvin') {
      this.celsiusToKelvinConversion ();
}
if (this.inputUnit === 'Celsius' && this.targetUnit === 'Rankine') {
      this.celsiusToRankineConversion ();
}
```

If's for Fahrenheit, If's for Kelvin, If's for Rankine, etc..
and what about if in the feature I want to add a different kind of unit?
What would be a better approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the cleanest way to handle this would be using a switch statement. It doesn't get simpler than that, I personally hate it as well but sometimes there is just no way around it really.

```
switch(this.inputType) {
  case 'Celsius':
    switch(this.targetUnit) {
      case 'Fahrenheit':
        this.celsiusToFahrenheitConversion();
        break;
      case 'Kelvin':
        this.celsiusToKelvinConversion();
        break;
      case 'Rankine':
        this.celsiusToRankineConversion();
        break;
    }
    break;
  case 'Fahrenheit':
    break;
  case 'Rankine':
    break;
  case 'Kelvin':
    break;
}
```

However! This is a mathematical conversion. F° to C° `(32°F − 32) × 5/9`, F° to Kelvin is `(32°F − 32) × 5/9 + 273.15`, F° to Rankine is `32°F + 459.67` and so on. And where is math, there is a system. My approach would be creating a conversion table - an object, and use the form values as lookup values. For example:

```
const magicalLookupTable = {
  celsius: {
    fahrenheit: () => {
      /** Implementation */
    },
    kelvin: () => {
      /** Implementation */
    }
  },
  fahrenheit: {
    celsius: () => {
      /** Implementation */
    },
    kelvin: () => {
      /** Implementation */
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I look at this I see compound keys set against a function value.

One way to represent this idea is with an typical object where the keys are the compound and they map to a specific function:

```
const conversionFunctions = {
    'celsius-fahrenheit': this.celsiusToFahrenheitConversion,
    'celsius-kelvin': this.celsiusToKelvinConversion,
    'celsius-rankine': this.celsiusToRankineConversion
};

const key = `${this.inputUnit.toLowerCase()}-${this.targetUnit.toLowerCase()}`;
const convert = conversionFunctions[key];

convert();
```